# How can I express this nested loop in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

**Background:**

- I have ASP.NET Core app.  I'm trying to write server-side validation errors to the log.
- If ASP.NET Core model validation detects any error in any field in the webform, then `ModelState.IsValid` is false.
- Every field in the webform is listed in [ModelState.Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.valueenumerable)
- If a "Value" has one or more errors, then Value.Errors.Count > 0
- I want to log a) the webform field name (the Value's "key") and b) each error message for that field.
- I'd like to include all this information in a single line (i.e. a single C# "string").

**Current code:**

```
// LOG:
//   2022-10-24 09:37:29.0909|Error|ServiceMenu.Q255: The value '' is invalid. 
//   2022-10-24 09:37:35.4096|Error|ServiceMenu.Q265: The value '' is invalid. 
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    foreach (var k in ModelState.Keys)
    {
        var v = ModelState[k];
        if (v.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            string s = k + ": ";
            for (int i=0; i < v.Errors.Count - 1; i++)
                s += v.Errors[i].ErrorMessage + ", ";
            s += v.Errors[v.Errors.Count - 1].ErrorMessage;
            _logger.LogError(s);
        }
    }
    return Page();
}
```

**Sample output (two required fields, Q255 and 265, were blank):**

```
2022-10-24 09:37:29.0909|Error|ServiceMenu.Q255: The value '' is invalid. 
2022-10-24 09:37:35.4096|Error|ServiceMenu.Q265: The value '' is invalid.
```

Q: Can I simplify this nested loop with LINQ?

Comment: Your loop has side effect (LogError), and it's usually not a good idea to use LINQ while you have side effects, so I'd personally would not "simplify" this loop.

Comment: You could, however, simplify the inner string construction as `string s = k + ": " + string.Join(", ", v.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));`  Less mechanism, more intent.

Comment: 1. you have closure here `_logger` https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/
.. 2. Don't think that using linq is always good. Even though sometimes in complex cases it is possible, often you get hard to read code.
3. Even in LINQ you often use multi-line predicate.
4. for this case it is something like `.where(.key has error.).groupby(. by key.,select(. one string for all errors for key.)).toList(.get list of key/error pair.).ForEach(..print long error per key..)`

Comment: @Paul: the purpose of the edit here is to move the answer material into the correct space, as noted in the CW answer below. A downvote on that post doesn't change the fact that this is a very normal amendment for editors to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var logMessage = string.Join("\n", ModelState.Keys
        .Where(x => ModelState[x].Errors?.Count > 0)
        .Select(x => $"{x}: " + string.Join(", ", ModelState[x].Errors.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage))));
        
    _logger.LogError(logMessage);
}
```

Comment: this writes 1 message for all keys. I think - must be per key. I could be wrong

Comment: @T.S. you can remove String.Join though, then it will return array of error messages, and then you can run foreach to output them one by one.

Comment: @T.S. You are correct but what's the point of writing multiple log messages when they are all correlated?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold I am just saying about correlation of output of your solution vs OP.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

Notes:

- Evk and T.S. are both absolutely correct: *"Don't think that using LINQ is always good."*  I don't - and their point is very well taken :)
- Oliver Weichhold gave me the syntax I was looking for :)

Here's the code I finally wound up with:

```
  // EXAMPLE LOG:
  //   2022-10-24 13:24:10.5242|Error|ServiceMenu.Q255: The value '' is invalid. 
  //   2022-10-24 13:24:24.9692|Error|ServiceMenu.Q265: The value '' is invalid. 
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      foreach (var k in ModelState.Keys)
      {
          var v = ModelState[k];
          if (v.Errors.Count > 0)
          {
              string s = string.Join(", ", ModelState[k].Errors
                  .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
              _logger.LogError(k + ": " + s);
          }
      }
      ...
```